# How exactly does React make this.props available in a class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`If you want to use this.props in the constructor, you need to pass props to super(). Otherwise, it doesn't matter because React sets .props on the instance from outside immediately after calling the constructor.`

So I'm curious how exactly does React sets .props in a class based Component right after calling the constructor if constructor lacks of super(props) or there is no constructor at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the constructor lacks `super(props)` (which calls the parent constructor with the given arguments) then `this.props` will not be set, however if the entire constructor is missing the parent constructor will be called because when making a class based component you must extend from `React.Component`.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused because I red some old docs from when it was possible to call super() without arguments.

Comment: You can still call `super()` without arguments but you won't have any props.

Answer (score -1):

You won't get the props if you don't call super(props) in the constructor...